# Dynamic Javascript regexp to replace a string containing variable data

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a JS regexp that allows me to replace a string containing variable data. For example, i want to replace this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

with this:

```
Stylesheet: style.css
```

However, the filename is a variable. How can i do such kind of dynamic regexp in JS?

Comment: No, they can be anything. From ABC.CYZ to null.css

Comment: The contents of href.

Comment: I want to replace the entire string, but i want to keep a part of it as a variable, to use in the replacement string.

Comment: So capture that part in a capturing group ?

Comment: Sort of like backreference in PCRE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Exactly that, then you can use the back references in the replacement string.

Comment: But why use regular expressions? My own approach would be to parse the created-DOM: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FJgJa/). Does this miss something?

Comment: I would do the same as David. If this doesn't do it for you, I'd need more examples to cater the regex to. Will you only be handling `<link ref="stylesheet"` elements and are you only searching for the `href` or also other tags/properties?

Answer (score 0):

My own approach to this question would be to use a function to create, temporary, nodes from the HTML string and then parse those created nodes for the relevant information:

```
function resourceTyping (htmlString) {
    var _tmp = document.createElement('div'),
        data = {
            html: htmlString,
            props : []
        };
    _tmp.innerHTML = htmlString;
    var children = _tmp.childNodes,
        rel, href, nodeHTML;
    for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
        rel = children[i].rel || '';
        href = children[i].getAttribute('href') || '';
        nodeHTML = children[i].outerHTML || '';
        if (children[i].rel && children[i].href && nodeHTML.length) {
            data.props.push(
                {
                    'rel' : rel,
                    'href' : href,
                    'nodeHTML' : nodeHTML,
                    'typeAndValue' : rel[0].toUpperCase() + rel.substring(1) + ': ' + href
                }
            );
        }
    }
    return data;
}

var html = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /><a href="something.html">text</a>',
    details = resourceTyping (html);
console.log(details);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FJgJa/1/).